# "Invalid hook call." when usin react useState Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

After researching many Stack Overflow forums I still don't know why my code keeps getting the dreaded "Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:" error.

My code is pretty simple and basic to understand, I'm using a function to render formatters to put into a cell component and I decided to use Hooks to get a React state on if a checkbox is checked or not. Here is the code :

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
export function checkbox()
{
    const [checked, setCheckbox] = useState(false);

   
    let line_id = this.params.line_id
    let checkedValue = ''
    let checkedString = ''

    if(checked)
    {
        checkedString = ' checked'
        checkedValue = 1
    }
    
    return(
        <td key={line_id} className='fixedWidth field_checkbox' style={{width: '18px'}}>
            <div id={'checkbox'+line_id} className={'text center styled_checkbox'+checked} onClick={() => setCheckbox(prevChecked => !prevChecked)}>
                <input type={'checkbox'} name={'id['+line_id+']'} value={lineId} className='styled_checkbox' />
                <input type={'hidden'} name={'changed_id['+line_id+']'+line_id} id={'changed_id['+line_id+']'+line_id} />
                <input type={'hidden'} name={'checked_id['+line_id+']'+line_id} value={checkedValue} id={'checked_id['+line_id+']'+line_id} />
            </div>
        </td>
    )
}
```

This function is supposed to render in a  component in a html table.

Comment: Function component name needs to start with Uppercase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I basically found ou why my Hook wasn't working. I found out hooks can't be used inside loops and I was initiating on in a .map function. Would have been nice for the React team to put it in the error message in the debugger but at least I won't make the same mistake again and hope the forum post will be able to help some other people like me just getting started with Hooks.

Thanks to all of you guys for the help !

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you are using `checked` value inside the return statement in your `div`

```
  <div id={'checkbox'+line_id} className={'text center styled_checkbox'+--->checked<---} onClick={() => setCheckbox(prevChecked => !prevChecked)}>
```

I've put `--->` and `<---` in the code where the mistake is.

Answer (score 0):

Below code working fine for me

```
<input
          type={"checkbox"}
          name={"id[" + line_id + "]"}
          value={checked}
          className="styled_checkbox"
        />
```